# Piping an Image Through a Non Static Array of Functions in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to re a Photoshop Adjustment Layer style process where image processing functions are representing by layers in a stack, where the result of the top/first process is fed into the next process.
This could be represented as an array of processing functions, where the output of each function is fed into the next.

```
[Change Brightness(img)->Change Saturation(img)->Change Levels(img)]
```

How could I achieve this kind of 'handing off' of a value from a nonstatic array of functions in Rust?

```rust
fn op_a(mut a: Vec<u8>, p1: i32) -> Vec<u8> {
    //process image
    println!("Operation A on image with size: {}, and parameter1 val: {}", a.len(), p1);
    a[0] = 10;
    a
}

fn op_b(mut a: Vec<u8>, p1: i32, p2: i32) -> Vec<u8> {
    //process image
    println!("Operation B on image with size: {}, parameter 1 val: {}, parameter 2 val: {}", a.len(), p1, p2);
    a[0] += 2;
    a
}

fn op_c(mut a: Vec<u8>, p1: i32, p2: i32, p3: i32) -> Vec<u8> {
    //process image
    println!("Operation C on image with size: {}, parameter 1 val: {}, parameter 2 val: {}, parameter 3 val: {}", a.len(), p1, p2, p3);
    a[0] *= 2;
    a
}

fn pipe_function_array(initial_image: ImageBuffer, Vec<functions>)->ImageBuffer{
        //executes an array of functions passing each to the next function in the array, with an initual input value of initial_image
    
}

fn main() {
    let my_starting_value =  *some Vec<u8>*;
    let my_funcs = *an array of op_a, op_b, and op_c*;
    let final_image = pipe_function_array(vec![0], my_funcs);
}
```

[image: ps adjustment layers]

Comment: If you are not adding or removing elements from the vec, consider using a mutable slice, which is `&mut [u8]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code basically works once you fix the obvious syntax errors.

```
fn op_a(mut a: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    //process image
    println!("Operation A on image with size: {}", a.len());
    a[0] = 10;
    a
}

fn op_b(mut a: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    //process image
    println!("Operation B on image with size: {}", a.len());
    a[0] += 2;
    a
}

fn op_c(mut a: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    //process image
    println!("Operation C on image with size: {}", a.len());
    a[0] *= 2;
    a
}

fn pipe_function_array(initial_image: Vec<u8>, a: Vec<fn(Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<u8> {
    //Using fold here, but you can easily just use a for loop if you prefer.
    a.iter()
        .fold(initial_image, |image, operation| (operation)(image))
}

fn main() {
    // You have to define the type of the Vec here, 
    // otherwise the compiler will throw some ambiguous errors.
    let my_funcs: Vec<fn(Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>> = vec![op_a, op_b, op_c];

    let final_image = pipe_function_array(vec![0], my_funcs);
    dbg!(final_image);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d8dded105a0b67e8f3ae419fae0e863)

---

Instead of directly passing function pointers however, I would suggest taking a different approach of using an array of enums.

```
enum Operations {
    Saturation {
        config: SaturationConfig,
    },
    Contrast {
        config: ContrastConfig,
    }
}

fn saturation(mut a: Vec<u8>, config: SaturationConfig) -> Vec<u8> {
    //process image
    a
}
fn contrast(mut a: Vec<u8>, config: ContrastConfig) -> Vec<u8> {
    //process image
    a
}

fn pipe_function_array(mut initial_image: Vec<u8>, a: Vec<Operations>) -> Vec<u8> {
    a.iter()
        .fold(initial_image, |image, operation| match operation {
            Operations::Saturation { config } => saturation(image, config),
            Operations::Contrast { config } => contrast(image, config),
        })
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! If I wanted to add additional parameters at each of these stages that control those op_ functions, how could I pass those parameters in a at each stage as well? I.e a threshold function would have a value of 5, then the saturation function would have a value of 20, etc.

Comment: @ANimator120 Instead of directly passing in a Vec of function pointers, I would probably replace the function pointers with a `enum` that contains different variants for each operation, plus the additional values for each particular operation.